# ImportError: No module named djangocms_* attempting for runserver?

Tags: python, django

Uesterday I installed django-cms on my django project. After setting infrastructure for django-cms in `urls.py` and `settings.py`. I wanted to start server by `python manage.py runserver`, but I faced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
django.setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named djangocms_file
```

Here's my settings.py contents:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'students',
'home',
'cms', 
'treebeard', 
'menus',
'south',
'sekizai',
'djangocms_admin_style',
'djangocms_file',
'djangocms_flash',
'djangocms_googlemap',
'djangocms_inherit',
'djangocms_picture',
'djangocms_teaser',
'djangocms_video',
'djangocms_link',
'djangocms_snippet',
)
```

The error is same for all `djangocms_*` plugins. What's the problem?

Comment: Have you installed djangocms?..

Comment: Yes. I've installed it already!

Comment: Ok.. Have you installed it in the correct environment your running in? does it show up in pip freeze *in the environment/env* your running the server

Comment: **does it show up in pip freeze in the environment/env your running the server**
How can I check it buddy?

Comment: just type `pip freeze` into the command window in whatever environment your project runs in

Comment: Yes, There it is. django-cms==3.2.2

Comment: Oh.. It was a silly mistake.. :/ Everytime I ran the server I was not in **env**.
But now a new error :(((( `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: I installed all `djangocms_*` plugins via `pip` outside `env` and inside my project directory. **The errors gone!**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. First it showed ModuleImportError: No module named djangocms_admin_style and on commenting that line out, the next line popped out.

This error happened because I forgot I used a virtual environment and hadn't activated it first before trying to run the server.

So quite simply, activate the environment used and rerun python manage.py

[image: Failed to run python django server]

[image: Successfully ran python django server]

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your virtual env

```
$ pip install djangocms-snippet
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).